# Android 12 APK throws invalid package upon install

Tags: android, azure-devops, xamarin.android, apk

I have an Azure build pipeline which is producing an APK which installs (via AppCenter) just fine on Android 10 but pops up the error:

> App not installed as package appears to be invalid

on Android 12.

The `AndroidManifest.xml` in the solution looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.app.myapplocal" android:installLocation="auto" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.1">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="31" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <application android:label="L MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:largeHeap="true"></application>
</manifest>
```

When I examine the manifest via Android Studio's `APK Analyze` option, I see this:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:label="D MyApp"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f07015e"
    android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.MainApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0001"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f07015e"
        android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:configChanges="0x680" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0000"
        android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.FormAuthenticatorActivity" />

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.WebAuthenticatorActivity" />

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator Native Browser"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.WebAuthenticatorNativeBrowserActivity"
        android:launchMode="1" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity" />

    <service
        android:name="crc64a98abb514ffad9f1.KeepAliveService" />

    <receiver
        android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver"
        android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="mono.android.MultiDexLoader"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.app.myapp.mono.android.MultiDexLoader.__mono_init__"
        android:initOrder="1999999999" />

    <provider
        android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.app.myapp.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__"
        android:initOrder="1999999998" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@ref/0x7f090008" />
</application>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

I had previously thought that the problem with Android 12 was that the `android:targetSdkVersion` was set to `29` but changing this in the solution's manifest and changing the project file's `TargetFrameworkVersion` from `v11.0` to `v12.0` did not help either. (This was updated in Visual Studio using the project properties' `Application > Compile using Android version` value.)

What might I be missing in order to allow installing on recent Android devices? (I am not familiar with Xamarin or Android, I'm afraid.)

Comment: You have to grab a logcat on install time to get more details about an error, because `package appears to be invalid` isn't helpful at all

Answer (score 10):

If you have bumped the compile version to 31, then you need to add

```
android:exported="true"
```

To your activities, services and receivers. See [here](https://cafonsomota.medium.com/android-12-dont-forget-to-set-android-exported-on-your-activities-services-and-receivers-3bee33f37beb).

In your case

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="31" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.FLASHLIGHT" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:label="D MyApp"
    android:icon="@ref/0x7f07015e"
    android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.MainApplication"
    android:debuggable="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:extractNativeLibs="true">

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
        android:value="barcode" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0001"
        android:label="MyApp"
        android:icon="@ref/0x7f07015e"
        android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:configChanges="0x680"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x7f0d0000"
        android:name="crc646948444ac10504e5.SplashActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="1"
        android:noHistory="true">

        <intent-filter>

            <action
                android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category
                android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.FormAuthenticatorActivity" 
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.WebAuthenticatorActivity" 
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:label="Web Authenticator Native Browser"
        android:name="crc641e66d166111bdf3e.WebAuthenticatorNativeBrowserActivity"
        android:launchMode="1"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <activity
        android:name="com.microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.authentication.RedirectUrlActivity"
        android:exported="true"/>

    <service
        android:name="crc64a98abb514ffad9f1.KeepAliveService"
        android:exported="true"/>
    <receiver
        android:label="Essentials Connectivity Broadcast Receiver"
        android:name="crc64a0e0a82d0db9a07d.ConnectivityBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <receiver
        android:name="crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.PowerSaveModeBroadcastReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false" />

    <provider
        android:name="mono.android.MultiDexLoader"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.app.myapp.mono.android.MultiDexLoader.__mono_init__"
        android:initOrder="1999999999" />

    <provider
        android:name="mono.MonoRuntimeProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:authorities="com.app.myapp.mono.MonoRuntimeProvider.__mono_init__"
        android:initOrder="1999999998" />

    <activity
        android:theme="@ref/0x01030010"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiActivity"
        android:exported="false" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@ref/0x7f090008" />
</application>

<uses-permission
    android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Please be wary of what really needs to be exported or not and change accordingly.

It could also be the case that App Center as of Android 11 requires a mandatory app signer, see [here](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/2293#issuecomment-984374114), [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/build/android/code-signing), and just in case, here is the snippet

> As of Android 11, it's mandatory to use the APK signer (if you use API level 30) as it will set some extra schemes "APK Signature Scheme v2 now required". App Center now (since Dec 17, 2020) signs Android applications using APK signer internally, instead of JAR signer which was used previously. As part of the feature to enable APK signer in App Center, Android signing task V3 was implemented, and requirements for new Signing task were to change how keystore file is saved - to store the keystore file in an AzDO secure file (Android signing build and release task - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs).

> Warning
> Any build configurations that had their keystore files uploaded prior to Dec 17, 2020 still use the APK Signature Scheme v2 signing method (jarsigner). To use the APK Signature Scheme v3 signing flow, users just have to re-upload their keystore files and save their branch configuration.

Comment: Trying to identify what the activity, service or receiver entry in my manifest is. Could you indicate which line contains those, please?

Comment: The link posted shows an example

Comment: I understand that the produced manifest contains those things, just not what they are in my solution's manifest. I have posted the complete manifest from the APK. Should I be adding entries into my solution manifest's `<application>` element and decorating them with `android:exported`?

Comment: I will update my answer with the corrected manifest you have provided

Comment: I understand that the resulting manifest file in the apk should look like what you've posted, but if you see the manifest in my actual solution, it contains very little. How do I configure it for activities, service and receivers when I do not know what they are? AFAIK they are being added during compilation.

Comment: Hmm, ok, understood. I added an extra solution in the case that this would be your issue

Comment: @LethalMaus legend. In my case, simply re-uploading the exact same keystone file within App Center did the trick.

Comment: You only have to add `android:exported="true"` in tags which contain an `<intent-filter>`, not in all tags. Check the doc [here](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#exported)

Answer (score 2):

> **App Not Installed As Package Appears To Be Invalid [Fixed]**

After changing **compileSdkVersion , targetSdkVersion to 31** ,
If anyone getting this above error  on **Android 12 / 13 preview version**. Update all of your dependencies to latest one and Please add -

```
android:exported="true"
```

to any `<activity>, <activity-alias>,<service>, or <receiver>` components that have `<intent-filter>s` declared in the app’s inside **AndroidManifest.xml** file. After that do `gradlew clean` and to test the changes create a new device with android 12/13 configuration in your **android emulator**  and to install this app from **release version** you have to run this command `npx react-native run-android --variant=release`

Answer (score 0):

It may be that it doesn't like the [install location](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element#install) "auto", resulting in:

```
android:installLocation="0"
```

Which should be one of:

```
android:installLocation=["auto" | "internalOnly" | "preferExternal"]
```

Comment: If I read the documentation you linked to correctly, the two allowed values for that property are `auto` and `preferExternal`. I have `auto`.

Comment: Without console output, this basically is a duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=INSTALL_FAILED_INVALID_APK

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"` is commented out within your app `build.gradle`.

Like that:

`//compileSdkPreview = "UpsideDownCake"`