# Signed apk unable to install in Android 12

Tags: android, cordova, apk, quasar, jarsigner

I got '**App not installed as package appears to be invalid**' message when trying to install my signed release app manually on Android 12. However, it can be installed in my other phones which are Android 9 and Android 6.

I use **jarsigner** to sign my apk :

```
$ jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA256withRSA -digestalg SHA-256 -keystore my-release-key.keystore <app-release-unsigned.apk's path> alias_name
```

And use **zipalign** to optimize :

```
$ zipalign -v 4 <path-to-same-apk-file> HelloWorld.apk
```

I've change my phone setting so that able to install unknown apk and **tested with app-debug.apk and it works just fine**. For more information, my app is written by using **quasar framework** and built by using **cordova**.

Comment: Why are you doing it by hand rather than letting gradle sign it for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android 12 APK throws invalid package upon install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71022310/android-12-apk-throws-invalid-package-upon-install)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Android 12, you have to use V2 signing scheme to sign your APK. Unfortunately, jarsigner is only v1 signing scheme.

In short, **use apksigner to sign your APK** in place or jarsigner, or if you use Android Studio, don't forget to check the "V2 signing" check box or define the signingConfig enabling v2 signing.

Comment: OMG it works using apksigner, thank you so much !!!

Comment: A note here is that the order of zipalign and jarsigner/apksigner matters (check the docs for zipalign)